# How to prevent a specific branch from being merged in git?

Tags: git, githooks

We have a `master` branch where the released production code lives, a `dev` branch where the code for the test server lives, and various feature branches (branched from `master`) as each developer sees fit.

Over the course of time the `dev` branch has diverged somewhat from `master`. In addition, there are some incorrect merges there that mess up parts of the code. Several times already we have tried to reset (force-push) `dev` to be the same as `master`. To start over with a clean slate, so to say.

Unfortunately this does not last long. Sooner or later someone merges the old `dev` into the new `dev`, bringing back all the mess with it. I suspect this might even happen automatically, where a naive `git pull` silently merges the old and new branch heads.

Is it possible to prevent this with a server-side commit hook? Something that would refuse to accept the `git push` if the wrong commit is merged in?

Comment: "Sooner or later someone merges the old dev... I suspect this might even happen automatically". It's not git by itself, someone is doing it. If you are using github or gitlab, you can protect your branch `dev` to direct push, merging branchs only by Pull/Merge requests.

Comment: Hunt through the inbounds in pre-receive, if you see anything you don't like, refuse the push.

Comment: Actually... I just came up with a much simpler idea - create a `dev2` branch and use that for the test server. This way nobody can accidentally merge anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible with [Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/zh-tw/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#pre-receive). Put the following POC script to `.git/hooks/pre-receive` on your remote (server-side) repository and give it right permission to execute.

Configure the branch you want to protect, for example `master`

```
$ git config hooks.protected-branch.refs master
```

File: .git/hooks/pre-receive

```
#!/bin/sh

read old_value new_value ref_name

refs=$(git config hooks.protected-branch.refs)

for ref in $refs; do
    if [ "$ref_name" == "refs/heads/$ref" ]; then
        if [ "$old_value" == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ]; then
            continue
        fi

        if ! git merge-base --is-ancestor "$ref_name" "$new_value"; then
            echo "$ref_name is protected branch"
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
done
```

When you try to reset `master` by force-push, You will get similar output like this:

```
Counting objects: 12, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 920 bytes | 153.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 12 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: refs/heads/master is protected branch
To ../demo
 ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to '../demo
```

Answer (score 0):

> Sooner or later someone merges the old dev into the new dev, bringing
>   back all the mess with it.

This is a common problem when using the default `git pull` behavior.  To
avoid it, it's possible to configure `git pull` to use `rebase` by
default instead of `merge`.  That is, to rebase the current branch onto
the remote branch instead of merging it:

`git config pull.rebase interactive`

From the [`git-config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) man page:

> pull.rebase
>
> When `true`, rebase branches on top of the fetched branch, instead of
>   merging the default branch from the default remote when "git pull" is
>   run. See "branch..rebase" for setting this on a per-branch
>   basis.
>
> When `preserve`, also pass --preserve-merges along to git rebase so
>   that locally committed merge commits will not be flattened by running
>   git pull.
>
> When the value is `interactive`, the rebase is run in interactive
>   mode.
>
> NOTE: this is a possibly dangerous operation; do not use it unless you
>   understand the implications (see git-rebase(1) for details).

With that, whenever the remote branch is rewritten (with `push -f`),
whoever is pulling is responsible for identifying and dropping the "old"
commits during the rebase.  This results in a clean history (i.e.: no
merges of "old" versions) on each branch.

Answer (score -2):

GitHub has a feature called protected branches, which gives repository administrators the ability to disable force pushes to specific branches.

In addition to blocking force pushes, a protected branch can have required status checks.

for more information...
Please check https://blog.github.com/2015-09-03-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks/